# Find $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ such that inequality is true

Tags: real-analysis

Find all $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_0^{\infty} x\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+1\right)^{\alpha}dx \le 1$

Of course, it must be that integral is covergent, so $\alpha < -1$ $\leftarrow$ it is fairly easy.  However, I don't know for which $\alpha<-1$ it fullfill this inequaliy. So I ask for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Try just explicitly computing the integral by making a substitution $u=\frac{x^2}{2}+1$.

Comment: Did you mean $\int_0^{\infty}u^{\alpha}du$ ?  $$\int_0^{\infty}u^{\alpha}du = \lim_{r\to\infty} \int_0^{r}u^{\alpha}du=...$$ I can't finish it.